# PHP not displaying properly

Tags: php, html-table

I am having an issue on designing a web page. I want to display a POST variable inside of an HTML table.

Here is the form code from the first page:

```
<form action="buy.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="uid" />
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" />
</form>
```

This code works fine if I am displaying the POST variable on a normal blank PHP file.

But when I go to use it in an html table it just won't display.

Here is the table code:

```
<td id="bal"><?php echo $_POST['uid']; ?></td>
<td id="amt">test1</td>
<td id="type">test2</td>
```

The first tabledata just appears blank.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is the entire code in the buy.php file: http://pastebin.com/ffWAP92C

(was having trouble posting it in here )

This is what the problem looks like:

[image]

Comment: I assume that you have the table and tr tags in place.  If you cant single step through it then  I would suggest do a var_dump($_POST['uid']) before the table tag

Comment: Starkeen could you please elaborate? You don't mean an if statement do you? There's no need for one here.

Comment: Rohit yes I do have the table and tr tags. How will dumping the variable before the table help display it inside of the table?

Comment: the above code works fine for me. did you use any `css` or `jquery` in your code

Comment: Make a simple check by replacing the code with <?php echo "BLABLA"; ?>. Check if the static text will appear. By the way is the mentioned file with html table is buy.php or it is some else?

Comment: No there is no css or jquery. @Jithin Varghese

Comment: @KanchoIliev It is buy.php. It does appear when the table is removed from the document.

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);` in the start of the page where you use `echo $_POST['uid'];` and tell us what you see

Comment: It means your table is malformed. If you like answer it is better to show us whole code

Comment: it is better to show the whole code.

Comment: I think the problem is with your table.

Comment: Whole code of buy.php http://pastebin.com/ffWAP92C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `<td id="bal"> <?php echo "$_POST['uid'];" ?> </td>` to `<td id="bal"> <?php echo $_POST['uid']; ?> </td>`

Try this one,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <center><h1>Purchase Account ID</h1></center>
    <table border="1" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
           <td><b>Account ID</b></td>
           <td><b>Account Type</b></td>               
           <td><b>Account Price</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td id="bal">
               <?php
                   if(isset($_POST['uid']))
                      echo $_POST['uid'];
                   else
                      echo "Nothing";
               ?> 
           </td>
           <td id="amt">test1</td>
           <td id="type">test2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: @Chawbee :- can you please post your whole code. So that i can analyze.

Comment: @jithin_varghese No it didn't :\ This is actually what I had before. I just inserted the quotes to see if it would work. It shows up like this: http://prntscr.com/6v4yo6

Comment: @jithin_varghese There still isn't anything displayed in the box. Didn't even print out the "nothing" .

Comment: @Chawbee :- are you running the code in localhost `(using wamp server, xampp server etc...)` or just opening with browser.

Comment: @jithin_varghese I feel like such an idiot right now  -__- . Thanks, that was it. How do I rep you/give you best answer? Fairly new to the site still

Answer (score 0):

Remove " signs inside php tag. i.e. replace

```
<td id="bal"> <?php echo "$_POST['uid'];" ?> </td>
```

with

```
<td id="bal"> <?php echo $_POST['uid']; ?> </td>
```

OR insert semicolon after " sign. i.e.

```
 <td id="bal"> <?php echo "$_POST['uid']"; ?> </td>
```

Comment: can you post the source code of first page, not buy.php

Answer (score 0):

you can copy past below code in a test.php file. i have updated code. It is working in my localhost.

```
        <html>

        <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">


        </style>
        </head>
        <center><h1>Purchase Account ID</h1></center>




        <body>
        <table border="1" style="width:100%;">
          <tr>

            <td><b>Account ID</b></td>
            <td><b>Account Type</b></td>               
            <td><b>Account Price</b></td>


          </tr>

          <tr>

                <td id="bal"> <?php if(isset($_POST['uid'])) echo $_POST['uid']; ?> </td>
                <td id="amt">test1</td>
                <td id="type">test2</td>


          </tr>

        </table>

        </body>


        <form action="test.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="uid" />
        <input type="submit" value="Buy Now" />
        </form>

        </html>
```